# How does the 'level' parameter of groupby method in Pandas works?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

```
(df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)['CENSUS2010POP']
   .agg({'avg': np.average, 'sum': np.sum}))
```

In the above code, why is it necessary to specify the level parameter in groupby, because as per my understanding the level parameter is only required when we have multiIndex in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No only `MultiIndex`, it should be used in `Index` too, because there is only one level.

Also for function [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with specified column for aggregate is necessary pass list of tuples for specifies name of new columns with aggregated functions:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP']
         .agg({'avg': np.average, 'sum': np.sum}))
```

> FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
>   is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
>    .agg({'avg': np.average, 'sum': np.sum}))

---

But your code should be simplier:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':list('aab'),
                   'CENSUS2010POP':[10,20,50]})

df1 = (df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP']
         .agg([('avg', np.average), ('sum', np.sum)]))
print (df1)
        avg  sum
STNAME          
a        15   30
b        50   50
```

Also if really need create index from `STNAME` column or is already in DataFrame in [last versions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements) of pandas (0.20+) working:

```
(df.set_index('STNAME').groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP']
   .agg([('avg', np.average), ('sum', np.sum)]))
```